# Under what conditions do you need to prescribe select into so that the trigger works?

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I have two Cars and Trip tables. I need to create a trigger that verifies that the number of tickets sold (number_tickets from Trip) does not exceed the number of seats in the car (number_siding from Cars).
In the trigger, I fetch data to compare their values, in the condition number_tickets I attribute ': new.' so that it checks the new parameter being entered.

The problem is that it displays the error

> ORA-01422: extract fetch returns more than requested number of rows.

Question: under what conditions do you need to prescribe select into so that the trigger works?

```
create table cars(
                  shifr_car     integer not null,
                  state_number  integer,
                  number_siding integer,
                  shifr_mark    integer,
                  shifr_driver  integer,
                  primary key(shifr_car)
);

create table trip(
                  shifr_trip     integer not null,
                  shifr_day      integer,
                  shifr_way      integer,
                  time_output    date,
                  shifr_car      integer,
                  number_tickets integer,
                  primary key(shifr_trip)
 );
```

-- foreign key shifr_car

```
alter table trip 
add(constraint shifr_car foreign key (shifr_car) references cars(shifr_car));
```

-- trigger's code

```
create or replace trigger check_place
   before insert or update on trip
   for each row
declare
    id_car trip.shifr_car%type;
    numb_siding cars.number_siding%type;
    number_tickets trip.number_tickets%type;
begin
    select shifr_car into id_car from trip;
    select number_siding into numb_siding from cars where shifr_car = id_car;
    select number_tickets into number_tickets from trip;
    if(:new.number_tickets > numb_siding) then
        dbms_output.put_line( 'Проданных билетов больше, чем мест в автобусе');
    end if;
end;
```

Comment: Regarding the error message: say you have 50 rows in `trip` and you run `select shifr_car into id_car from trip;` That will attempt to put all 50 values into `id_car`, which of course it can't do because `id_car` can only hold one value. You need to limit the query so it only picks one value, or else rethink what you are trying to do there.

Answer (score 0):

The current error might raise due to any of three Select Statements and expected whenever any of the tables has more than one row.

You should use a Statement Level trigger instead of Row Level trigger by removing `for each row`. Since, just needed to compare the totals from those tables. Moreover, you can get the mutating trigger error with the current case. So, consider using the following code in order to recreate the trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER check_place
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON trip
DECLARE
  numb_siding    INT;
  number_tickets INT;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(number_siding) INTO numb_siding FROM cars;
  SELECT COUNT(number_tickets) INTO number_tickets FROM trip;
  
  IF number_tickets > numb_siding THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Проданных билетов больше, чем мест в автобусе');
  END IF;
END;
/
```